# How do I barplot only the first 10 entries in a frequency table in R

Tags: r, plot

If I create a frequency table with the follow code:

```
mytable <- table(data$column_data)
```

How would I barplot only the first 10 entries for this table? My current barplot code is the following, which of course plots the whole table:

```
barplot(mytable, main = "Title", xlab = "column_data", ylab = "Frequency",col='coral')
```

Comment: Do you need `barplot(mytable[1:10], main = "Title", xlab = "column_data", ylab = "Frequency",col='coral')`

Comment: Wow, akrun, that it. I was tearing my hair out. Thanks!

Comment: @akrun And use `sort` too, if you want the 10 highest frequency, rather than 1st 10.

Comment: Gold. Many thanks too dww. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with `[` or `head`

```
barplot(mytable[1:10], main = "Title", xlab = "column_data", ylab = "Frequency",col='coral')
```

Or as @dww mentioned, it can be `sort`ed as well

```
barplot(sort(mytable)[1:10], main = "Title", xlab = "column_data",
              ylab = "Frequency",col='coral')
```

Comment: And sort option `decreasing =TRUE` to get highest frequencies